# Enable CSRF prevention using Spring security through XML configuration

Tags: java, spring-mvc, spring-security

I am using Spring 4.1.6 and spring-security 4.0.1 in my web application.
I have gone through many posts enable csrf using spring security in my application. Still I do not found a solution. I am not getting the csrf token in my jsp. They are still null. My normal web MVC application is working fine, but having issues with setup of security.

The following changes that I have done to enable security is

**Added following jars:**
spring-security-core-4.0.1
spring-security-web-4.0.1
spring-security-taglibs-4.0.1
spring-security-config-4.0.1

**Added SecurityConfig class**

```
import org.apache.log4j.Logger;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import  org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter;

@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    private Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(SecurityConfig.class);

    @Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

    logger.debug("Inside configure method of SecurityConfig class....");
    http
            .authorizeRequests()
            .anyRequest().permitAll();
}
}
```

Added this filter in web.xml

springSecurityFilterChain
        org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy

```
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

Please help.

I am getting exceptions like

> SEVERE: WebModule[/AG_INDREVIEW]PWC1270: Exception starting filter springSecurityFilterChain
>   java.lang.InstantiationException
>
> WARNING: WEB9052: Unable to load class org.springframework.security.web.context.AbstractSecurityWebApplicationInitializer, reason: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/web/WebApplicationInitializer

Answer (score 0):

It seems that your main problem is to install and deploy Spring security properly. Are you sure that all your spring jars are deployed to your web container?

The WebApplicationInitializer class usually is in spring-web-4.x.x-RELEASE.jar. Can you cherk if your WEB-INF/lib contains this jar?

Comment: Yes, I am sure about Spring web jars, because all the other web functionality is working fine. I am only having issue when I am adding the security configuration. I have the spring-web-4.x.x-RELEASE.jar under  WEB-INF/lib folder. I also tried changing the versions of jars thinking that there might be some conflicts. But still it doesn't work.